# knockout <!-- ko if --> not working

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

So i have this code in my ui:

```
<!-- ko if: $data.Volume.locator.volume_labels.containername ===  $parent.DockerContainer.Names[0].split('/')[1] -->
<div class="ctrdisk" data-bind="css: { diskup: $data.Volume.runtime_state.RuntimeState == 'clean', diskdown: $data.Volume.runtime_state.RuntimeState != 'clean'}">
    <span data-bind="text: $data.Volume.locator.volume_labels.containername ===  $parent.DockerContainer.Names[0].split('/')[1]"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This somehow shows me the div class inside, even when the if statement is not true.
to test this i print the result of this statement inside of a span as yo can see.

i see both true and false.

any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: I had bad experience with `<!-- ko ... -->` style. If you'll fail to solve problem, i suggest to rewrite it to plain old observable-subscribe code.

Comment: Your system may be stripping comments.

Comment: please put parenthesis and hope it will work.. <!-- ko (if: $data.Volume.locator.volume_labels.containername ===  $parent.DockerContainer.Names[0].split('/')[1]) --> . if it didnt worked then please create a fiddle for the same.

Comment: Please make sure your question contains a [mcve] when (like in this case, seemingly) it is feasable. Without it others can only reseort to *guessing* at the answer.

Comment: Roy J you were correct. my revel is stripping the comments out.